# A proof of a known identity using Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

**The exercise**

> Let $f$ be a $2\pi$ periodical function defined as $f(x)=\cos ax, \; |x|\leq \pi, \; a \notin \mathbb{Z}$. Expand $f$ in a Fourier series and prove that:
>   $$\pi \cot \pi a = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+a}, \; a \notin \mathbb{Z}$$

The Fourier series is pretty straight forward. By evaluating the coefficients one gets that:

$$\cos ax = \frac{\sin \pi a}{\pi a}+ \frac{2a \sin \pi a}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \cos nx}{(a-n)(a+n)} \overset{x=\pi}{\implies }\\ 
\overset{x=\pi}{\implies}\pi \cot \pi a =\frac{1}{a}+ 2a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a-n)(a+n)}$$

How do I derive the series from $-\infty$ to $\infty$? I cannot see how to manipulate the last series in order to get what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Note that for the substitution $n \to -n$ the series is unchanged.  Thus, the sum over non-zero integers is twice the sum over the positive integers only.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Sure, thanks for you answer.

Comment: Pleased to hear!  And you're most welcome. It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Evaluate
$$\frac1{a+n}+\frac1{a-n}\,.$$

Comment: We can't split a convergent series into a sum of two divergent (harmonic like) series

Comment: Well, yes, that's a good observation. Nevertheless, it rather says that interpreting the desired formula $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{n+a}$ is not straightforward (if possible in any way).

Comment: I did not get your point.

Comment: @berci The series you wrote diverges.

Comment: Well, how is this sum over $n=-\infty..\infty$ defined exactly?